# Login form : no redirection to the allowed pages

Tags: php, forms, authentication

First of all, English is not my native language, and it's late and i'm searching this from noon. So please, be indulgent.

I have a problem with a simple login form. Well, this login form is so simple that I thought I wouldn't have any issues...

**What I did :** 
So, I created a page index.php which contains the login form. When sent, the script verify if the fields are filled, connect to DB, check with the datas in DB, and if password and login are correct, it starts a $_SESSION and fill the $_SESSION['login]. Then it redirects the user to a page with back-office content, by a session_start and a check to the $_SESSION['login'].
In theory, it would work.

But no.

**What is the issue :**
when i enter the information in the login form and send it, the same page reloads and does not redirect me to the backoffice page. ZERO ERROR LAUNCHED

**My codes :**
*index.php*

```
<?php 
    include('functions.php');
    login();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 ...
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="main">
 <h2>Authentification</h2>
 <form name="iam" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
   <label for="login" class="iconic comment"> Login <span class="required">* </span>
   </label>
   <input type="text" required="required" name="login" id="login">
   <label for="mdp" class="iconic comment"> Password <span class="required">* </span>
   </label>
   <input type="password" required="required" name="mdp" id="mdp">
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

login() into *functions.php* :

```
<?php
include_once('conf/connec.php');
$connect_db=connect();

function login() {

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

            if(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['mdp'])) {

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT mdp, login FROM 2K13_id WHERE login = '".md5($_POST['login'])."'");

                if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
                    $user = mysql_fetch_object($query);

                    // On vérifie la concordance des mots de passe (en md5)
                    if(md5($_POST['mdp']) == $user->mdp) {     
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['login'] = $user->login;
                        header("Location:backoffice.php");

                    } else {
                        echo 'Mauvais mot de passe pour cet utilisateur.';
                    }

                } else {
                    echo 'Ce login n\'existe pas dans notre base.';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Vous devez remplir tous les champs !';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

AND the bunch of code before every html declaration in my *backoffice.php* :

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        die("NO PASARAN");
    }
```

I really don't know why i'm turning around : I checked all passwords and login, every header. (To avoid possibles problem with header, i even try with a dirty js inclusion

```
echo '<script>document.location = "backoffice.php"</script>';
```

I'm a little despair, so if you could help me or just turn on a light on a possible mistake/php error, i would be totally thankful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing your input tags. Instead of

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="login" id="login">
<label for="mdp" class="iconic comment"> Password <span class="required">* </span>
</label>
<input type="password" required="required" name="mdp" id="mdp">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Write

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="login" id="login" />
<label for="mdp" class="iconic comment"> Password <span class="required">* </span>
</label>
<input type="password" required="required" name="mdp" id="mdp" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

Also, check to see if you are entering `if` with header redirect. You must not have any html output before it, including empty space. And url should normally be absolute, not relative, so add `http://...`

Comment: Hi @Marko , thanks for your time and your answer, I did close my input tags (_even if not closing them is the new way to write <input> in HTML5_), and I checked : the `if` : it is entered. I checked if I did not write my include with some space, or if i call Html before the header : nope...So, I have no idea why my file is not lanched... but thanks for the propositions!

Comment: and did you try with absolute url?

Comment: yes. With the right path. Doesn't work. May it come from my host, not allowing header's redirections?

Comment: Well, I don't know what I did (tried several little modifications, likecalling the login() function in very FIRST (before in my file, there were some commented code), so maybe that's why it works now. 
Anyway, thanks for your time @Marko!